# AngularJS TypeError: "track" is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

I am trying to call a service with parameters from my controller method and I get an error saying that it is not a function. Here is my code:

```
(function (){

angular.module('app.uploadedReleases')
        .controller('UploadedReleasesController', UploadedReleasesController)
        .controller('ModalController', ModalController);


UploadedReleasesController.$inject = ['$log', '$scope', '$modal', 'ReleaseService', 'TrackService'];
function UploadedReleasesController ($log, $scope, $modal, releaseService, trackService){

        vm.selectTrack = selectTrack;

       function selectTrack(album, track, index){

        trackService.currentTrack(album.slug, track.fileName).then(function(responseValue){
            vm.temp = responseValue;
        });
        vm.formTrack = vm.selected.track;
    }
}
```

Here is my service called trackService:

```
angular.module('app.services')
        .service('TrackService', TrackService);

TrackService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

function TrackService($http, $q){
    var trackService = {};

    var releasesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/releases';
    trackService.currentTrack = currentTrack;

        function currentTrack(releaseSlug, trackSlug){
        var trackUrl = releasesUrl + '/'+ releaseSlug + '/' + trackSlug + '/track';
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get(trackUrl).then(function(trackResponse){
            return deferred.resolve(trackResponse);
        }, function(error){
            return deferred.reject({msg: 'Error while getting the current track details'})
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

Any idea why I would get the error in my controller: `TypeError: trackService.currentTrack is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very 1st thing I'd say that is, you are creating a service then you should bind method to `this` context, rather creating object.

```
var trackService = {};
```

would change to

```
var trackService = this;
```

But returning custom object from service isn't wrong also. So in current situation you missed to returned it. At the end of your service code to add

```
return trackService
```

Still confused how service & factory work, I'd recommend to readup on [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262966/2435473)

---

You should return a promise from `trackService.currentTrack` method which you had created in custom way.

```
trackService.currentTrack = currentTrack;
function currentTrack(releaseSlug, trackSlug){
    var trackUrl = releasesUrl + '/'+ releaseSlug + '/' + trackSlug + '/track';
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(trackUrl).then(function(trackResponse){
        return deferred.resolve(trackResponse);
    }, function(error){
        return deferred.reject({msg: 'Error while getting the current track details'})
    });
    return deferred.promise; //returned promise
}
```

---

Rather you should be do your custom promise which is consider as anti-pattern to implement where you have promise returned by `$http.get` method, You should utilize that.

**Refactored Version**

```
trackService.currentTrack = currentTrack;
    function currentTrack(releaseSlug, trackSlug){
    var trackUrl = releasesUrl + '/'+ releaseSlug + '/' + trackSlug + '/track';
    return $http.get(trackUrl).then(function(trackResponse){
        return trackResponse;
    }, function(error){
        return {msg: 'Error while getting the current track details'};
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj Parkar. I added the `return deferred.promise` and still have the same issue.

Comment: @noobcoder its really hard to understand what is `vm.selectTrack = selectTrack`? and then where does `vm.formTrack = vm.selected.track;` come from ?

Comment: They are just objects I defined like: `vm.formTrack = selectTrack` as a return value from the function selectTrack

Comment: @PankajParkar see https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md for a rundown on the controllerAs vm style

Comment: @water42 Thanks for the link to JohnPapa's style guide. I was referring that only

Comment: @noobcoder could you look at updated answer please.. thanks ;)

Comment: @water42 LOL :D :D :D.. you got me wrong.. I didn't ask OP that what `vm` stands for & how it works?, I was just asking him, how code flow is going on.. I was lost when, I was trying to understand whats going on with code..so thats why I asked him about my confusion..

Answer (score 3):

@Pankaj Parkar's answer is correct in that you should be returning a promise from `currentTrack` in order to chain `then` in your controller.

However, to answer your question about the TypeError, you're mixing factory and service syntax here in `TrackService`.

To make it a factory, return a map of the exposed functions:

```
function TrackService($http, $q){
    var trackService = {};
    trackService.currentTrack = currentTrack;

    function currentTrack(releaseSlug, trackSlug){
        //...
    }

    return trackService;
}
```

and declare with `.factory('TrackService', TrackService);`.

To make it a service, add the exposed functions to `this`:

```
function TrackService($http, $q){
    this.currentTrack = currentTrack;

    function currentTrack(releaseSlug, trackSlug){
        //...
    }
}
```

and declare with `.service('TrackService', TrackService);`.

Comment: I already did figured out in my answer.. still good finding +1

Comment: @nickgraef In my Service I am doing the same thing. `var trackService = {}`

Comment: @noobcoder it's not the same because in a service it needs to be bound to `this`, and in a factory, you need to return the trackService object

Comment: @water42 aah I get it now. Thanks. Also, I realized I was not returning `trackService` in my service. +1 But I'd mark Pankaj's answer as correct. He did point that out first. I'll upvote your answer. Thanks guys

Comment: @noobcoder If you are still confused with it, you could do go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28262966/2435473) would you help you with understanding behind service/factory/provider.